# issue with deploy Angular 9 SSR app to fire base

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, firebase, angular-universal

I converted my app and deployed follow the instructions here

[Error with angular 9 SSR and fire base cloud functions #2369](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2369)

now in the last step of deploying I get this error

```
Built at: 04/01/2020 4:18:16 PM
  Asset      Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
main.js  3.93 MiB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
Entrypoint main [big] = main.js
chunk    {0} main.js (main) 7.37 MiB [entry] [rendered]
⚠️ Your Node.js version (13.12.0) does not match the Firebase Functions runtime (10).
Deploying your Angular Universal application...
success.hosting.split is not a function
PS C:\Users\Khaled\Desktop\coupons>
```

Comment: From the error it  tells like firebase and your application is using different nodejs versions.try match the version.

Comment: did it with nvm, did not work as well

Comment: Can you share the error log